# use of 'def' in pandoc scripts

Tags: haskell, pandoc

If you look at the pandoc documentation you see scripts written in Haskell.  I have only recently learned the basics of Haskell so I am unfamiliar with some of the idioms that seem to appear in these scripts.

One of the things that I don't understand is the use of `def` in these scripts.  For example, at the top of [Text.Pandoc](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.12.4.2/docs/Text-Pandoc.html) is the following code:

```
 markdownToRST :: String -> String
 markdownToRST =
   (writeRST def {writerReferenceLinks = True}) . readMarkdown def

 main = getContents >>= putStrLn . markdownToRST
```

What does the 'def' do after the `readMarkdown` and the `writeRST`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In Haskell, `def` is just a variable name, nothing special. The `def` in this code is [`Data.Default.def`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default/docs/Data-Default.html#t:Default) from the [data-default](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default) package. It is used to access a default value. The default value it returns depends on the type it is used at. In this case, it returns the default writer options and default reader options, respectively.

To figure such things out, you can use [hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle) to search for names or types in the API documentation of Haskell packages. In this case, you can search for [+pandoc def](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=%2Bpandoc+def) to search for the name `def` in the pandoc API documentation. The first result is [`Text.Pandoc.Options.def`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#v:def). I was confused by the type signature of `def`, so I clicked on the `Default` type class in the signature which took me to the documentation of the `data-default` package.

The documentation of the `Default` type class doesn't mention `ReaderOptions`, because the data-default package doesn't know about the pandoc package. But in Haskell, type classes are open, so the pandoc package can add the `instance Default ReaderOptions` itself. See the list of instance in the documentation of [`ReaderOptions`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#v:ReaderOptions). Or see the source code for the actual `instance Default ReaderOptions` declaration [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc/docs/src/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#ReaderOptions).

Comment: Yeah.  I saw the data-default package but it doesn't have anything for ReaderOptions or WriterOptions so I wasn't sure if I was looking in the wrong place.  Also, the `def :: Default a => a` still confuses me a bit.

Comment: Actually, what I should have said was that I understand that the `Default a => a` simply limits `a` to being a type of `Default`, but didn't quite know where to go to find out more about the actual default values or what was being returned in each of the uses of `def` above.  I'm still getting used to the Haskell way of doing things and the documentation isn't always as clear to me as I would like it to be.

Comment: I see. In this situation, I tend to hunt down the actual instance declaration in the source code (I start with the "source" link in the API documentation of the type, in this case, `ReaderOptions`).

Comment: Ah.  I didn't even *see* the "source" link.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

It comes from the [`Text.Pandoc.Options`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.12.4.2/docs/Text-Pandoc-Options.html) module, which itself is importing it from [`Data.Default`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/data-default-0.5.3/docs/Data-Default.html), where it's defined simply as

```
class Default a where
    def :: a
```

It's just defining a "default" value for types that implement it, very similar to `mempty` from `Monoid` but without the restriction that you define `mappend`.

Comment: Thanks.  This helps a lot, though I would like to find somewhere that this is documented (along with what those default values actually are).

Comment: @melston If you're looking for the defaults for `ReaderOptions` and `WriterOptions`, those will be defined in `Text.Pandoc.Options`.  If you look at the documentation, it has each of them as instances of the `Default` typeclass. If you want the defaults, the easy way would be to load up GHCi and type `:m Text.Pandoc.Options` followed by `def :: ReaderOptions`, otherwise just look [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.12.4.2/docs/src/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#ReaderOptions) and [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/pandoc-1.12.4.2/docs/src/Text-Pandoc-Options.html#WriterOptions)

Comment: @melston I see by your other comment that you're confused by `def :: Default a => a`.  What specifically about it confuses you?  All it's saying is that for some type `a` that implements `Default`, there is a value `def` with type `a`.  For example, the instance for `Int` would be `instance Default Int where def = 0`.  That's it, nothing special.  Another would be `instance Default [a] where def = []`.  It's all just to define default values for various types, and the `data-default` package has many defaults written for built-in types already.

Comment: Yeah.  I wasn't very clear about that.  I added a comment just now clarifying it.  In Haskell-speak `def` is a function that returns an `a` where `a` must be of type `Default`, right?  I was trying to link this whole thing with the `readMarkdown` and `writeRST` and was getting lost in the process.  Your answers helped put be back on track.  Thanks.

Comment: @melston Yes.  `def` is a function _that takes no arguments_ that returns a value of type `a` where `a` is an instance of the `Default` typeclass.  It knows what type to return based on context, so if I said `def + (1 :: Int)`, the compiler knows that `def` has to be an `Int` and pulls in `Int`'s instance to substitute in.  In the pandoc case, it sees that each of those functions requires `ReaderOptions` and `WriterOptions` values, so it pulls in the instances for those types defined in `Text.Pandoc.Options`.